# Fetch an image from Node.js with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a simple server in Node.js.
I am trying to fetch an image from it which is generated dynamically.
Unfortunately something is wrong and I cannot find where is the problem.

ndServer.js
    var gm = require('gm');//http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/

```
if (url = pathname.match(/^\/color\/([0-9a-fA-F]{6})/)) {
    var hex = url[1];
    if (hex in cache) {
        complete(cache[hex]);
        return;
    } else {
        var gw = gm(20, 20, '#ffffff00')
                .fill('#' + hex)
                .stroke('white', 0)
                .drawEllipse(20 / 2 - 0.5, 20 / 2 - 0.5, 20 / 2 + 0.5, 20 / 2 + 0.5)
                .stream('png');
        var chunks = [];

        gw.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        gw.on('end', function (chunk) {
            var buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            complete(buf);
        });

        return;
    }
    function complete(buf) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
        res.write(buf);
        res.end();
    }
}
```

script.js

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/color/ffffff';

//Option 1
function loadImage(url) {

    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image()
        img.onload = function () {
            debugger;// never enter here
            resolve(img)
        }
        img.src = url
    })
}
var serverResponse = loadImage(url);

//Option2
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     contentType: "image/png",
     success: function (data, status, xhr) {

     debugger;//data = "", status = "success", xhr = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

     },
 });
```

In debugger Network I'm seeing all request but there is nothing in Preview `This request has no preview available.` The type of response is xhr.

The server is never firing `on('data', function(chunk){`.
In `function complete(buf){` the value of `buf = <Buffer >`.

In my opinion the problem is that it never fire `.on('data',function(chunk)`, but I don't know how to fix it

Any idea how can I fetch image from node.js and display it on client side?

I forgot to mention that I am working on Windows 10

Comment: This code appears too abbreviated to follow what is going on.  What exactly is the observed problem?  What does "something is wrong" mean?  What debugging/troubleshooting have you done and what have you learned so far?  In your script.js code, why are you calling `resolve(img)`?  I see no wrapping promise that would define ``resolve()` anywhere so the appropriate context to understand that code seems to be missing.  On the server-side what is `gm()`?

Comment: Also, what does your  ajax call return?  Do you check for errors on the ajax call?  Did you look in the debugger network tab to see what the server is responding with?

Comment: Whats img, where is that even instatiated?

Comment: I was to irritated yesterday and that's why so many information was missing. I add some comments and code.As much as I know I'm fetching some response but in my opinion this is not an image. Or I don't know how to get image from this resnponse